# Remove skew from one column in DataFrame by deleting rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame from which I’m trying to build a multiple linear regression model. The problem I have is that one of my Y variables is heavily skewed within the data set, so it’s weighting one side far too heavily. I need a way to normalize that one column, and the only way I can think to do that is to select and delete rows until I have an evenly distributed data set. I’ve built a simple example of what I’m talking about below. I would want column [0] to end up normally distributed by getting rid of the low tail. What’s the best way to go about doing this?

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import randn
from numpy.random import rand
from numpy import append
seed(1)
data=5*randn(100) + 10
tail = 10 + (rand(50) * 100)
data=append(data, tail)
data2=5*randn(150)+ 10
s1 = pd.Series(data)
s2 = pd.Series(data2)

df = pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to figure out a threshold value to discriminate which values belong to the tail (are too higher) and which not.

A very empirical way to do it is by visual inspection: plot an histogram of your data, and see where the tail starts.

```
plt.hist(df[0])
plt.show()
```

Using the sample data you provided, you could see that the tail starts at 20, so you can consider each value greater than 20 due to the tail of the distribution.

Of course, this is a very rough way. Depending on your real data, you may have a better way to define your threshold, maybe based on the theoretical model behind the data. I mean, I guess you should know or at least have an idea about why there is a tail in your distribution.

In any case, whatever criteria you use to define a `threshold` value (this is really up to you), once you have it you can simply set to `NaN` all the values greater than the threshold:

```
df[0].loc[df[0] > threshold] = np.nan
```

#### Disclaimer:

This approach may be considered unappropiate or wrong, because you are tampering with the data. I don't know what your final goal is, but be careful.

Comment: Yes, this was my initial approach. My problem with this is my actual data set (which I can’t share because it’s proprietary) has more than one spike, not just a tail. So I was hoping I could come up with some sort of function that would scan through the whole dataset and normalize it.

Comment: If you look at the histogram, all the spikes makes the tail of the distribution. So once you've figured the correct threshold, all spikes should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) for this. Use Skewness as objective function and try to minimize it. This should give you the samples that belong to an unskewed distribution. ([Example](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/RANSAC.html), [Example with different model](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ransac.html), [Example](https://medium.com/@iamhatesz/random-sample-consensus-bd2bb7b1be75))